# Alternative to GoDaddy?

Tags: dns, domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar

For a number of reasons I'm thinking about slowly moving my domains away from GoDaddy.  Unfortunately I don't know of a good alternative, and am looking for a recommendation.

To match what I currently use godaddy for it would have to offer:

- Full control over domains via web interface
- DNS service with web control interface. (preferably free, or reasonably priced)
- Private domain registrations (i.e anonymous whois data)

Any ideas?

Comment: There's no "right" answer to this question, but could be suitable for wiki.

Comment: [How I lost my $50,000 Twitter username](http://thenextweb.com/socialmedia/2014/01/29/lost-50000-twitter-username/#!uWGpu) - hacker reportedly gained access to GoDaddy account through lack of security.

Comment: I agree, 2-factor authentication would be a nice criterion.  We (read: my predecessor) lost a domain to GoDaddy because they *failed to remove us from DNS after expiry*, which caused a cascade failure. The credit card had expired, they notified us and we updated.  We assumed all was OK, since the site never went down.  My predecessor woke up one morning to find it's in the hands of a prospector.  Yes, that was their fault for not renewing 10 years forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ask for domains, as it seems, [Enom](http://www.enom.com), [Namecheap](http://www.namecheap.com), [Internet.bs](http://www.internetbs.net) are other options, and they've got good reputation.

Comment: Just moved from GoDaddy to NameCheap.  All the controls I needed were there, it was easy to move AND the NameCheap site runs much faster than GoDaddy ever did.

Comment: Yep, it gives you quite many options, and a good service . Glad that it helped. :)

Answer (score 3):

I moved most of my domains from [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com/) to [Gandi](http://www.gandi.net/) some while ago, mostly so domains can be managed separately from hosting. Gandi has a straightforward interface and feature set, allowing most common domain-related activities.

Comment: I have heard some really good things about Gandi. When I get the time, I'll probably move all my stuff from GoDaddy (for a huge number of reasons) to Gandi. +1

Answer (score 2):

[Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com) and [HostGator](http://www.hostgator.com) will likely fit the bill.  At the moment, I am experiencing better performance and service with HostGator.  Both are reasonably priced and offer the features that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I like [pairnic](http://pairnic) personally.

Answer (score 1):

It's not always clear when people say "move domains" if they mean just domain registration or registration+hosting.  It sounds like you're only concerned with registration in which case I concur with S.gfx above.

eNom, NameCheap, Google Domains, Hover and more... Like hosting I've had good and bas experiences with them all over the years.

If you're looking for registration+hosting then that's a different question though...

Answer (score 1):

I personnaly use surpasshosting and surpassdomains, never had problem with them, their support is really fast and they often did more than what my contract was including.

I also want to specify that I do not, and never did, work for those company, I am a totally satisfied customer.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using NameCheap.com for years. I love it and would recommend it to anybody. Coincidentally, I'd also recommend anybody to NOT use GoDaddy. For a number of reasons. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

It might help answer the question if we know at least some of the reasons why you're moving. Is it performance, the user-interface, customer service? There are 1000s of domain registrars offering all these services, so it helps to know your specific reasons why GoDaddy doesn't fit the bill.

1. What do you mean by 'full control'? What are you trying to do?
2. You can separate your DNS management with something like [Microtech](http://www.mtgsy.net/). They have a very flexible price structure.
3. Lots of registrars offer this, although many use DomainsByProxy, which is owned by GoDaddy. If your beef is with GoDaddy the company, this might therefore not be a solution. Both 123-reg.co.uk and NetworkSolutions.com offer their own service.

Comment: Just about *any* registrar will provide what's in the original question. This is currently wiki material at best.

Comment: @Su - not in my experience, hence the question.

Comment: @Su +1 for vote to move it to Wiki. The FAQ says 'avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”', which is basically this question. We have no idea what the OP means by 'full control', and there are 100s of hosting services that offer DNS control and private registration.